# How to make image visible when contained in a ViewBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, viewbox

I have added added an image to my layout,contained in a Viewbox but when I run the application the image `KinectVideo` doesn't show on screen.

Is there a property I'm missing in the layout orshould I rearrange the image in the layout to make it visible again?

This is how I have defined the layout:

```
<Window x:Class="BVversion1.ConditioningFrm"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ConStackPanelditioningFrm"  Height="377.612" Width="637.313">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">   
             <Button x:Name="pushUpBtn" Content="Push Ups" Width="100" Click="pushUpBtn_Click"/>
             <Button x:Name="burpeeBtn" Content="Burpee" Width="100" Click="burpeeBtn_Click"/>
             <Button x:Name="squatBtn" Content="Squat" Width="100" Click="squatBtn_Click"/>
             <Button x:Name="coreBtn" Content="Core" Width="100" Click="coreBtn_Click"/>    
            </StackPanel>
            <Image x:Name="KinectVideo" Width="640" Height="250" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <Button x:Name="homeBtn" Content="Home" Width="75" Click="homeBtn_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

Setting image source to bitmap:

```
KinectVideo.Source = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96,
                    PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel)
```

Comment: Where have you set the `Source` of `Image`?

Comment: @Rohit I added detail to question showing how I add source.This code works when the image is only element in viewbox but when I added buttons and stackpanel it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test with KinectVideo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ccac9a107581b343e832a2b040278b98?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); since we do not have your colorData and it works for me pretty fine.

Comment: I dont understand this code snippet,could you explain?

Comment: I let the source be an image from the Internet.